# Error handle for 2 floats separated by spaces in one line

Tags: c

This is my first try, but it didn't work.

It goes to INF loop if I enter the wrong input value intentionally eg: asdas dfsad afdas

```
float a,b ;
while (1){
    if(scanf("%f %f",&a,&b) == 2) {
        break;
    }
    printf("Error, try again:");
}
```

Comment: Since `scanf()` et al don't care about lines, they're the wrong functions to use if you care about lines. Read the input with a line-reading function ([`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)) and then parse the line with `sscanf()`. It doesn't care about newlines, but you know it has only got one line to play with. Further, if the first parse fails, you can reparse the line; you can also report the complete line in error messages, which can make debugging easier.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid this sort of problem is to use `fgets()` to read a whole line at a time, then parse it using `sscanf()` (or in your case, maybe `strtod()`).  This will not only avoid the specific problem you have now, but will also avoid other classes of problems when input format is not as expected.